# I would like to retrieve data from dataset after multi select and union C#

Tags: c#, sql, select, dataset, union

I want to retrieve data from dataset (visual studio 2010)
Here is the sql statement:

```
SELECT NO_IDENT_1 
FROM P240538 
WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/24}) 
Union 
SELECT NO_IDENT_2 
FROM P240538 
WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/24})
```

If I do one statement at once without the `union` it works.

```
string sqltring ="SELECT NO_IDENT_1 FROM P240538 WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/24}) Union SELECT NO_IDENT_2 FROM P240538 WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/24})"

OleDbConnection ConnFoxPro = new OleDbConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.S_ConnFoxPro26);
try
{
    ConnFoxPro.Open();
   // MessageBox.Show("  Connection State = " + ConnFoxPro.State);
}
catch (OleDbException ex)
{
    string errorMessages = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
    {
        errorMessages += "Index #" + i + "\n" +
                "Message: " + ex.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
                "NativeError: " + ex.Errors[i].NativeError + "\n" +
                "Source: " + ex.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
                "SQLState: " + ex.Errors[i].SQLState + "\n";
    }
    System.Diagnostics.EventLog log = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
    log.Source = "Mon application";
    log.WriteEntry(errorMessages);
    Console.WriteLine("Vous avez un exeption. Svp Contacter votre administrateur de system cdd ");
}
{

    try
{
    //MessageBox.Show(RqCompte);
    OleDbDataAdapter DA_ID = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqltring, ConnFoxPro);
    DataSet Ds_ID = new DataSet();
    DA_ID.Fill(Ds_ID, "P240538");

    foreach (DataTable thisTable in Ds_ID.Tables)
    {
        // For each row, print the values of each column.

        foreach (DataRow row in thisTable.Rows)
        {
           // string rowdata = row.ItemArray[0].ToString().Replace(" ", "");
            string rowdata1 = row["NO_IDENT_1"].ToString().Replace(" ", "");
            if (rowdata1 != "")
                liste_No_Ident += rowdata1 + " ";// +"NOMBRE = " + row["nbr_doublon"] + "\n\n";
            string rowdata2 = row["NO_IDENT_2"].ToString().Replace(" ", "");
            if (rowdata2 != "")
                liste_No_Ident += rowdata2 + " ";// +"NOMBRE = " + row["nbr_doublon"] + "\n\n";


        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Are you getting an error?  Data that doesn't look like it should?  What is happening?  Remember, a `UNION` doesn't return duplicate data.  Use `UNION ALL` if there will be duplicate data you want to see.  Please give more information of the output you're getting, and the output you want.

Comment: Suggestion: you might want to name your database objects something more descriptive than P240538...  Also: try running the sql manually against the database, I think you'll be surprised at what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you'd like to achieve you can save the union. Change your query to

```
SELECT NO_IDENT_1, NO_IDENT_2
FROM P240538 
WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/24})
```

You can leave your loop as it is.

If you want to go with the union solution a mix of the above statements is true and your query should look like this

```
SELECT NO_IDENT_1 AS NO_IDENT 
FROM P240538 
WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/24}) 
Union All
SELECT NO_IDENT_2 AS NO_IDENT 
FROM P240538 
WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/24})
```

Keep in mind that union queries should be avoided because they have a negative performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

The way `UNION` works is that the resultset has only the column name of the first `SELECT` but ALL rows (duplicates removed)... so you can't access a column by name `NO_IDENT_2`, only the value... the column name will still be `NO_IDENT_1` even if the data is from the second `SELECT` from the `UNION`

you can check that by accessing `thisTable.Columns.Count` - it will have the value 1 for the `SELECT` you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can only union data sets that have the same column definitions.  Column definitions are determined by the first set in the query, in this case the first column is named `NO_IDENT_1`.  If these columns had been different types the union would have failed completely.  If you want your code to work as written, you could change your query to:

```
SELECT NO_IDENT_1, NULL AS NO_IDENT_2
FROM P240538 
WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/24}) 
Union 
SELECT NULL AS NO_IDENT_1, NO_IDENT_2 
FROM P240538 
WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/24})
```

Here we made a dummy column in each query to be a placeholder for the column that doesn't exist in the other data set.

Or, you could alter your code to use something similar to below:

```
SELECT NO_IDENT_1 AS NO_IDENT, 1 AS SOURCE
FROM P240538 
WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/24}) 
Union 
SELECT NO_IDENT_2 AS NO_IDENT, 2 AS SOURCE
FROM P240538 
WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/24})
```

Here we use the same column in the result for the similar data, and added a new column to help us differentiate where the data came from.  If you don't care, you could always remove the Source column.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this:

```
SELECT NO_IDENT_1 AS IDENT
FROM P240538 
WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/24}) 
Union 
SELECT NO_IDENT_2 AS IDENT
FROM P240538 
WHERE (P240538.DATE_dt > {2011/04/24})
```

And change your loop to this:

```
    foreach (DataRow row in thisTable.Rows)
    {
       // string rowdata = row.ItemArray[0].ToString().Replace(" ", "");
        string rowdata1 = row["IDENT"].ToString().Replace(" ", "");
        if (rowdata1 != "")
            liste_No_Ident += rowdata1 + " ";// +"NOMBRE = " + row["nbr_doublon"] + "\n\n";
    }
```